# Changing text in a UILabel is causing all my imageViews and buttons to go back to their original locations

Tags: ios, objective-c

Whenever I try and change a labels text with

```
_levelNumberLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", difficulty];
```

it keeps moving all my labels, images and buttons back to their original location. I have never had this problem before, and I know its this line of code because it doesnt happen when I delete it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using auto layout and you've moved your interface around by setting the `frame` of your labels, images, and buttons. But `frame` and auto layout are opposites. Since you are using auto layout, you should have changed the *constraints* of your labels, images, and buttons.

So what's happening now is that you're setting the text of a label and this in turn is causing layout to happen. Layout, when auto layout is involved, means obeying the constraints. You didn't change the constraints, so, just as you say, this means that everything goes back to its original position - because that is what your constraints say to do.